# Why to I need to exclude from enableAutoConfiguration when I have autowired beans byname

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have 3 DataSource beans

```
<bean id="dataSource1" name="dataSource1" autowire="byName" .....>
<bean id="dataSource2" name="dataSource2" autowire="byName" .....>
<bean id="dataSource3" name="dataSource3" autowire="byName" .....>
```

I have set autowire "byName" in the beans in xml

I am creating 3 JdbcTemplates

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataSource1")
BasicDataSource dataSource1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataSource2")
BasicDataSource dataSource2;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataSource3")
BasicDataSource dataSource3;


@Autowired
@Bean(name="jdbcTemplate1")
public JdbcTemplate createJdbcTemplate(){
         return new JdbcTemplate((DateSource)dataSource1)
} 

@Autowired
@Bean(name="jdbcTemplate2")
public JdbcTemplate createJdbcTemplate(){
         return new JdbcTemplate((DateSource)dataSource2)
} 

@Autowired
@Bean(name="jdbcTemplate3")
public JdbcTemplate createJdbcTemplate(){
         return new JdbcTemplate((DateSource)dataSource3)
}
```

StackTrace :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-11-16 23:50:04.562 ERROR 15180 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field dataSource1 in com.MyClass required a single bean, but 3 were found:

```
- dataSource1: defined in class path resource [datasource.xml]

- dataSource2: defined in class path resource [datasource.xml]

- dataSource3: defined in class path resource [datasource.xml]
```

Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed

When I add **EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})** everything works fine.

Can anyone explain why do I need to exclude the AutoConfiguration despite autowiring-byName.

Comment: how is dataSource1, dataSource2, dataSource3 defined ?

Comment: Sorry , missed that part. Have updated the question. Have tried both with & without @Qualifier annotation (as I think that is unnecessary as I have already declared autowire-"byName")

Comment: Can you put the exact stacktrace

Comment: Added. Is it possible that @EnableAutoConfiguration tries to inject beans ignoring the autowiring criteria ?

Comment: Springboot will try to do DataSourceAutoconfiguration by default as soon as it see any database related dependencies in your pom.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to ignore the auto-configuration, you just need to mark one of the datasources as `@Primary`, as auto-configurations might try to get one by type. This leads to the error you have.

Also, feel free to check [the dedicated section in the reference documentation about dealing with multiple datasources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-two-datasources); there are better ways to configure multiple datasources and still leverage Spring Boot features and infrastructure.

Comment: My problem is I can't mark any datasource is primary as I need all three of them mapped respectively. The autoEnableConfiguration with exclude I am getting the proper beans. But I want to understand why autowire byName and @Qualifier is ignored while  creating beans by spring.